# seek in salsa20

Tags: c, cryptography

Using Salsa20, how would one seek to a byte position (assume it's a multiple of 64) (using the public domain C implementation at http://cr.yp.to/snuffle/salsa20/merged/salsa20.c

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
void seekIV(unsigned long int pos) {
int low_32bits, high_32bits;

pos /= 64;

low_32bits = pos & 0xffffffff;
high_32bits = (pos >> 32) & 0xffffffff;

printf("\n SEEKING TO %lu\n", pos * 64);

ctx.input[8] = low_32bits;
ctx.input[9] = high_32bits;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'OH... the answer is... I forgot to also fseek in the stream ;)

Comment: LOL, that saved me a lot of time trying to understand what Bernstein thinks, a hard thing to do at any point in time.